# which is the difference betwwen this two ways to refresh the dbContext?

Tags: entity-framework-4, concurrency, refresh

I am using EF 4.4 and I would like to update many entities, but some other user can modified many of the entities that the first user is modified. So I get a concurrency exception. Other case is that the first user tries to add many new registers and other user added some of them meanwhile. So I have an exception that exists some of the registers (unique constraint).

I would like to ensure that the first user finish his operation add only the registers that does no exists yet (add all his entities except the entities that are added by the second user).

To do that, I need to update the entities in my dbContext so I see that there at least two options.

First, in the catch when I capture the update exception, I can do:

```cs
ex.Entries.Single().Reload();
```

The second option is:

```cs
myContext.Entry<MyTable>(instance).Reload();
```

I guess that the second option only refreshes the entity that I use as parameter, but if the problem is that I need to refresh many entities, how can I do that?

What really does the first option, `Single().Reload`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```cs
ex.Entries.Single().Reload();
```

you are sure that the offending entity is refreshed. What is does is taking the one and only (`Single`) entity from the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException.Entries` that could not be saved to the database (in case of a concurrency exception this is always exactly one).

When you do

```cs
myContext.Entry(instance).Reload();
```

You are *not* sure that you refresh the right entity unless you know that only one entity had changes before `SaveChanges` was called. If you save an entity with child entities any one of them can cause a concurrency problem.

Comment: and if there are many offending entities, all of them are refreshed or only one by one?

Comment: There's always just one. EF saves each object individually and the first one that causes a collision throws the exception. Of course there can be more that _would have_ caused collisions, but they've not been saved yet, so EF doesn't know they should be refreshed. They will get noticed the next time you try to save.

Answer (score 0):

In EF 6.x (6.1.3), below code will let you find all the changes; the way you asked in your question!

```cs
try
{
  var listOfRefreshedObj = db.ChangeTracker.Entries().Select(x => x.Entity).ToList();
  var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)your_db_context).ObjectContext;
  objContext.Refresh(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.RefreshMode.ClientWins, listOfRefreshedObj);

  await db.Entry(<yourentity>).ReloadAsync();
  return Content(HttpStatusCode.<code>, "<outputmessage>"); ;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  return Content(HttpStatusCode.<code>, "<exception>");
}
```

**Explaination:**
Query `Entries` in the `ChangeTracker` and store them in a list

```
var listOfRefreshedObj = db.ChangeTracker.Entries().Select(x => x.Entity).ToList();
```

Next is to refresh the context. In some cases (row is removed etc.), this will throw an exception which you can catch. `RefreshMode.ClientWins` tells EF to accept all client units as modified when next update occurs. In some cases, you might want to prompt the users with the changes and let them decide. [RefreshMode Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.refreshmode(v=vs.110).aspx). An example is here [ObjectContext.Refresh Method Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
objContext.Refresh(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.RefreshMode.ClientWins, listOfRefreshedObj);
```

You're probably doing this whole thing after you receive `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` anyways!